# Append values corresponding to a unique label as a list of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a dataframe:

```
df  =      A    B
       0   a    1
       1   b    2
       2   a    3 
       3   d    4
```

I want to update it like:

```
df  =      A    B
       0   a    [1, 3]
       1   b    [2] 
       2   d    [4]
```

Comment: You could do that, but pandas does not works well with list. Care to expand on the reasons you want to do that?

Comment: df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(list) but no recommend

Comment: actually I have a dictionary like: {A:[a, b, a, d], B:[1, 2, ,3, 4]}, how to make it like: {A:[a, b, d], B:[[1, 3], 2, 4]}

Comment: Then for loop will needed to create the dict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) column `A` and convert the grouped elements in `B` to lists with [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df.groupby('A').B.apply(list).reset_index()

   A       B
0  a  [1, 3]
1  b     [2]
2  d     [4]
```

Comment: I need that column name 'B' too

Comment: Okay, updated. Simply convert it to a dataframe. The result from the groupby was a series

Comment: @SrGrace this so called reset_index

Comment: its not what is actually required, please look at the updated df